# Is there way I can specify a favicon without using images?

Tags: html, css, favicon

My code to set up favicons looks like this:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon-retina.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon-ipad.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/Images/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

I am using vector icons everywhere in my application now.

Does anyone know if there is a way that I can specify the favicon that the browser uses as a vector icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [not supported by any browser at this time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) so you cannot do this.

Comment: This may sound like overkill (and it probably is!) but just for the sake of completeness - could he not have a route set up to `favicon` (+ whatever), which is handled by the server, the vector file is read, rasterized and returned as a binary stream? :)  Moo "Overkill is my middlename"  Juice.